# Outputting contents of a 2d arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Im strugging to get this code to work. What is supposed to happen is it creates an 2d arraylist, then adds some arraylist to that 2darraylist. Then taking user input and adding it to 2d array and tokenise it. Then output those tokenised inputs. The output should be so the first line will show the first arrayList then the second line will show the contents of the second arraylist and so on. Im getting the error message outofbound, size 5 size 5.

```
    String transState;
    trans = new ArrayList<List<String>>(5);
    ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    trans.add(t);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            transState = s.nextLine();
            trans.get(i).get(j).add(transState);
            trans.get(i).get(j).split(transState);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {  
            System.out.println( trans.get(i).get(j) );
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can see, `trans.get(i).get(j)` should throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException because the *inner* lists (i.e. `t`) are all empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is here:

```
ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList<String>(5);
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    trans.add(t);
```

You're adding the same `ArrayList` several times when you should add different `ArrayList`s into the principal `ArrayList`, like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    trans.add(t);
}
```

---

Apart of this, you will have a problem here:

```
trans.get(i).get(j).add(transState);
```

It should be

```
trans.get(i).add(transState);
//trans.get(i) returns List<String>
```

Also, this line makes no sense as is:

```
trans.get(i).get(j).split(transState);
```

Comment: Ive made the changes following your advice and im getting the error out of bounds index 5 size 5.

Comment: actually my mistake. i copied your code wrong. your way work fine thanks

Comment: do you know how i could tokenise my results. i want to make sure that if the user inputs more than one thing that is separated by a comma.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for: `transState = transState.replaceAll("\\s+", ",");` just before `trans.get(i).add(transState);`.